# how many bits I should put in stoi() function

Tags: c++

the following code will make the program crash:

```
            string test="b1";
            unsigned __int8 t1 = stoi(test, 0, 8);
```

but 'b1'=177, should be ok for a 8 bits, right? , if I use

```
string test="b1";
unsigned __int8 t1 = stoi(test, 0, 16);
```

everything looks ok, why need to use 16 bits for 'b1'?

a more complicate situation is 16 bits will make it right, but 32 bits make it wrong!!!

```
string test="0800";
```

`unsigned __int16 t1 = stoi(test, 0, 16);`

Comment: `std::stoi`'s third parameter has nothing to do with any number of bits.  It's the base that the number is represented in.

Comment: _"16 bits will make it right, but 32 bits make it wrong"_ -- this is subject to interpretation. Your question would be clearer if you specified what the "right" "it" is, and what the "wrong" "it" is. (E.g. you probably meant for "it" to mean the returned value, so what values are returned when the third parameter is 16 and 32?)

Comment: this is because I misunderstood the third parameters in stoi, I thought "base" is how many bits you try to convert, so when I said 16 bits /32 bits I thought everybody has the same understanding with me-------16 or 32 for the third parameter, I am surprised I am flagged and "-1" is added on my reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)'s third parameter has nothing to do with any number of bits.  It's the [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) that the number is represented in.

`2` means binary, `8` means octal, `10` means decimal, `16` means hexadecimal, etc. all the way up to base-36.  `0` means to determine the base from the prefix: strings starting with `"0x"` or `"0X"` are interpreted as hexadecimal, strings starting with `"0"` are interpreted as octal, and all other strings are interpreted as decimal.

When you call `std::stoi("b1", 0, 8)`, `std::stoi` will throw a `std::invalid_argument` exception since `b` is not a valid digit in base-8, and your program will crash if that exception goes uncaught.

`std::stoi("0800", 0, 16)` and `std::stio("0800", 0, 32)` are both totally valid, but of course 800<sub>16</sub> and 800<sub>32</sub> represent different numbers, so the two calls will return different results.

Answer (score 2):

Base 8 has exactly 8 different digits. Valid digits are the following:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Notice that `b` is not a valid digit in base 8. Only bases greater or equal to 12 have the digit `b`.

> if I use
>
> ```
> unsigned __int8 t1 = stoi(test, 0, 16);
> ```
>
> everything looks ok

16 is greater or equal to 12. `b` is a valid digit in base 16.